# Audio drivers, bluetooth drivers and wifi drivers don't work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.04, asus

I know you may think that this question has been answered in other threads. But the point is that I tried almost all things are said in all of these kind of threads and didn't work for me. I installed **Ubuntu** `17.04` in my `Asus-x205ta` laptop (which has been horrible, many problems with grub errors and UEFI) and now neither WIFI drivers nor audio drivers nor Bluetooth drivers work. Another interesting thing I found is that in "Software and updates", in the additional drivers section, I can choose one privative driver for the CPU, but not for Wifi, Bluetooth or audio.

The most important problem for my needs is the WiFi problem. 
As I said, I tried different things to solve the problem, that is to say, the most common ways to solve these problems.

Also I have read that this netbook has a lot of problems with Linux.

This is the output for `iwconfig`:

```
sergio@sergio-X205TA:~$ iwconfig
enx0050b61c7199  no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

And this is the output for `lscip`:

```
sergio@sergio-X205TA:~$ lsipc
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION                                              LIMIT USED  USE%
MSGMNI   Number of message queues                                 32000    0 0,00%
MSGMAX   Max size of message (bytes)                               8192    -     -
MSGMNB   Default max size of queue (bytes)                        16384    -     -
SHMMNI   Shared memory segments                                    4096    7 0,17%
SHMALL   Shared memory pages                       18446744073692774399 5248 0,00%
SHMMAX   Max size of shared memory segment (bytes) 18446744073692774399    -     -
SHMMIN   Min size of shared memory segment (bytes)                    1    -     -
SEMMNI   Number of semaphore identifiers                          32000    0 0,00%
SEMMNS   Total number of semaphores                          1024000000    0 0,00%
SEMMSL   Max semaphores per semaphore set.                        32000    -     -
SEMOPM   Max number of operations per semop(2)                      500    -     -
SEMVMX   Semaphore max value
```

And this is the output for `lsusb`:

```
sergio@sergio-X205TA:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 6557:5500  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b483 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please tell us the kernel you are running and if secure boot is activated or not in your BIOS.

Comment: in the past by accident I had disabled WiFi by hitting some keys ... assure you have not turned OFF WiFi from the keyboard ... issue   sudo apt-get install build-essential    then issue   dmesg    which displays system log messages which may show errors if any

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get install build-essential`  I get a message saying that this package was preinstalled. When I do `dmesg` I receive a huge message from the terminal, which exceeds the character limit for a comment or an edit.

Comment: Bad news: Asus X205ta is a glorified **Windows** tablet. It has serious issues with Linux and by serious I mean your audio will *never* work, WiFi *might work*. That aside the performance is poor. So, in a nutshell, use Windows. If you need Ubuntu buy another, decent laptop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I supose I have no other option, because I am studying computer science and mathematics, and laptops are fundamental for the uni. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xubuntu on my Asus X205TA (I used to use Debian then Lubuntu but they had a few oddities on the X205TA so I made the switch), here is what I did to get mine working with Xubuntu:

The prep work needed:

- Have 2 USB drives (We will call them B1 and B2), an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit ISO, and a Xubuntu 64bit ISO and another computer (not the X205TA)
- Use Rufus on the computer to make a Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB on the first USB drive (B1)
- Boot up the computer with the 14.04 Live USB (B1)
- Use the "startup disk creator" to make a Xubuntu Live USB with persistence on the second USB drive (B2)
- [Add this file](https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/blob/master/boot/bootia32.efi) to /EFI/BOOT directory of the Xubuntu flash drive (B2)
- Shut down the computer
- Ensure that the laptop is plugged in and charging
- Plug the Xubuntu Live USB drive (B2) into the laptop
- Plug in your internet access device
- Boot the laptop & press ESC as it is booting (this will give you the boot order screen)
- Select "enter setup"
- Disable Secure Boot
- Save and exit the BIOS
- Press ESC as it is booting (this will give you the boot order screen)
- Select your Xubuntu Live USB drive (B2) drive from the list
- Select "Try Xubuntu" when prompted
- Open the "Terminal Emulator" program

Type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility

Then do the following:

- Open the "Disks" program
- Find the laptops inbuilt storage and format it with a MBR/DOS partition system (top right, the gear)
- Once it is done use the "Install Xubuntu" program on the desktop to install it onto the laptops internal storage, make sure you have internet access on the laptop (USB cell phone tethering works well) and to select the option to install third party software.
- When the installation is complete you can shut-down the laptop & remove the USB Drive (but not your internet access device).
- Boot into your new install and log in

You now should have a semi working laptop, but as Billy Mays often said, "But wait there's more".

Open up the terminal and type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt dist-upgrade
- Install any updates shown
- sudo reboot

If you are installing 18.04 then your Wifi and MicroSD card reader should be working fine but if you are experiencing system frezes then use the fix in postscript 1, or Wifi stability issues then use the fix in postscript 4. If you are installing version **17.10 or earlier.** then follow postscripts 1, 2, 3, & 4 below.

---

^1 System freezes.

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Navigate to "/etc/default/"
- Open the "grub" file
- On the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" needs to be edited to read

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
- Save and close the file
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-grub
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot
- All going well you should not experience any random system freezes

---

^2 Wifi driver install for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

Open up the terminal and type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- cd /tmp
- wget https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/broadcom/wlan/+archive/master/bcmdhd/firmware/bcm43341.tar.gz
- tar xf bcm43341.tar.gz
- sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/brcm/
- sudo cp fw_bcm43341.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
- sudo mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
- sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
- reboot

---

^3 Micro SD Card Reader fix for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

- Open the text editor and type the following text (as shown) into it

  # Adjustment to make micro SD card reader work
    options sdhci debug_quirks=0x8000
- Save the file as "sdhci.conf" on the desktop

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Move the "sdhci.conf" file from the desktop to the directory "/etc/modprobe.d"
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot

---

^4 Wifi stability fix for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

- Open the text editor and type the following text into it

  blacklist btsdio
- Save the file as "fix-wifi.conf" on the desktop

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Move the "fix-wifi.conf" file from the desktop to the directory "/etc/modprobe.d"
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot
- All going well your Micro SD card reader should now be working and the Wifi should not be working erratically

---

**Note: As of the posting of this "how to" the laptops Bluetooth and sound are not supported and will not work, if you need either of them you will need a USB dongle.**

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you can try when you have driver issues is to use a more recent kernel. You can install a kernel easily with the Ukuu utility. See the [official website](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html).

Comment: probably not a good suggestion for new folks ... best to stick to stock matchings between Ubuntu releases and their pre-tested packaged drivers